# Android EditText

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext

I am a beginner in Android.
I have an EditText for one letter. It accepts only characters. I need to replace entered character with the new one when the user enters different character on the keyboard. How can I achive that? Is this possible?

```
// Set edit text width only to one character
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[2];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1);
    FilterArray[1] = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))
                        && !Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    editLetter.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expressions and replaceAll as in:

```
// ASSERT inString not null
public static String removeTags(String inString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (inString == null) {throw new IllegalArgumentException();}
    return inString.replaceAll("<.*>","");
}
```

This answer may or may not help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) should come in handy for this.

Comment: Thanks, I had implemented beforeTextChanged